# How to Store Image file temporary in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on django rest framework API, receive a image. I want to delete images after processing. I am not using any database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need this:

```py
class YourViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_uploaded = request.FILES['filename']
        process_file(Image.open(file_uploaded))
        return Response(status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If I'm remembering it correctly, Django would store the uploaded files within memory if the file is smaller than 2MB, or it will store in a temp directory, which will be cleaned up by django process itself. Also, check out the documents here: [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Answer (score 0):

[Tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) library is what you seek :)